# How do I enable Tomcat access logs in Grails 3?

Tags: grails

I am trying to enable access logs on the embedded Tomcat container in a Grails 3 app. I've already confirmed that the [one-line-access-log plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/one-line-access-log) is not sufficient for my purposes (certain resources being accessed - such as assets - don't get logged by that plugin).

I found some guides recommending you add this property to the application.groovy file:

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled = true
```

However that doesn't seem to do anything. Then I found other guides recommending the use of `eventConfigureTomcat` in `_Events.groovy`, however that seems to be a Grails <=2 paradigm.

What is the correct way to configure Tomcat to enable access logs in Grails 3?

Comment: Have you figured it out? I have the same need.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a way to get addition detail from Tomcat errors when starting a Grails application.  Have used this a number of times.

SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

To get the listener failed to start errors from Tomcat.  Go to your WEB-INF/classes directory, create file logging.properties with the following content and restart the tomcat server.

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level=INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler